# Disable SSH password authentication without root privileges

Tags: linux, ssh

I have an online shell as a free account on a website. From what I know, after I generate the SSH key pair and put the keys in the appropriate places, I should disable password authentication.

I found that it can be done by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then restarting the service. But there is a problem: I don’t have root privileges on the server, and the admin doesn’t seem very responsive.

So is there a method to disable pass auth all by myself, without said priviliges?

Comment: It is possible to disable the password authentication for only you or for everybody. But it has to be configured in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. So it needs elevated privileges.

Comment: I've written an answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/1050170/52492)

Comment: No problem, the server has automatically disabled password authentication for me, without admin intervention